# Newcomer's Rhyming Riddle V- What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> To make up sections in a chain;
>   It may come before a drain.
>   You're on the edge or almost there;
>   A ferret with the pricey hair.
>   Desire that is never bland;
>   A place for blades, but not in hand.
>   To give a signal with an eye;
>   Azaria as "science guy".
>   The sound of very uncooked ham;
>   The reason that I know I am.

**What am I?**

Comment: Is the intended solution for 5 slightly NSFW?

Comment: @Apep I guess, slightly. I probably wouldn't bring it up in the workplace myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> Ink

To make up sections in a chain

> Link

It may come before a drain.

> Sink

You're on the edge or almost there;

> Brink

A ferret with the pricey hair.

> Mink

Desire that is never bland;

> Kink

A place for blades, but not in hand.

> Rink : Skating rink, for the blades on the bottoms of skates

To give a signal with an eye;

> Wink

Azaria as "science guy".

> Frink : Hank Azaria voiced Prof. Frink in the Simpsons

The sound of very uncooked ham;

> Oink : sound a pig makes

The reason that I know I am.

> Think : "I think, therefore I am" - Descartes